# Show only one photo for each year in SPARQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sparql

My question is simple. But i can't get a grip on how to get it going with SPARQL.

I have a list of dates (format `YYYY-mm-dd`). For each date, i've created an `Event` (`schema:PublicationEvent`). `Photos` are linked to this `Event` when the `photo-date` and `event-date` are equal. Now i would like to make a list of **each year and show only one photo** per year. In my current query I get multiple photos per year. I would like to have one photo for each year. Could anyone help me out here?

```
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX spif: <http://spinrdf.org/spif#>
select distinct ?newDate (count(?photoRef) as ?photoCount)
from <http://archief.nl/events/Graph:anpGebeurtenissen>

PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX spif: <http://spinrdf.org/spif#>
select distinct ?newDate (count(?photoRef) as ?photoCount)
from <http://archief.nl/events/Graph:anpGebeurtenissen>
where { 
    ?dateEventURI a schema:PublicationEvent;
               rdfs:label ?dateEventLabel;
               schema:image ?photoRef.

    bind(substr(?dateEventLabel, "1", "4") as ?newDate)

} 
group by ?newDate ?photoRef
order by ?newDate
```

the result is like this. For 1937, there 3 URIs for photos shown. However, i'd rather see one photo (uri) for each year.

```
1   1937    http://test.nl/NL/doc/PhotoReference:A8BD26A2D0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
2   1937    http://test.nl/NL/doc/PhotoReference:AF33B3B6D0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
3   1937    http://test.nl/NL/doc/PhotoReference:AF33B906D0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
4   1938    http://test.nl/NL/doc/PhotoReference:AEC963E4D0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
5   1938    http://test.nl/NL/doc/PhotoReference:AEC964A2D0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
```

Comment: `SAMPLE(?photoRef)`? https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#aggregates

Comment: you should also remove the `?photoRef` var from the `group by` then, otherwise the `count` will always result in 1

Comment: `select distinct ?newDate (count(?photoRef) as ?photoCount) (sample(?photoRef) as ?photo)
from <http://archief.nl/events/Graph:anpGebeurtenissen>
where { 
    ?dateEventURI a schema:PublicationEvent;
               rdfs:label ?dateEventLabel;
               schema:image ?photoRef.

    bind(substr(?dateEventLabel, "1", "4") as ?newDate)

} 
group by ?newDate
order by ?newDate`

Comment: The thing with sample(?photoRef) did the job thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

`sample()` did the job. Thanks!

The query is as follows.

```
# Deze query toont voor elke jaar de referentie naar één foto
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX spif: <http://spinrdf.org/spif#>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
select ?year (sample(?photoRef) as ?photo)
from <http://test.nl/test/Graph:anpGebeurtenissen>
where { 

  ?dateEventURI a schema:PublicationEvent;
            rdfs:label ?dateEventLabel;
            foaf:img ?photoRef.             
  bind(substr(?dateEventLabel, "1", "4") as ?year)
} 
group by ?year
order by asc(?year)
```

The result looks like this

```
1   1937    http://test.nl/doc/PhotoReference:AF33B906D0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
2   1938    http://test.nl/doc/PhotoReference:AEC9690CD0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
3   1939    http://test.nl/doc/PhotoReference:AF74502ED0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
4   1946    http://test.nl/doc/PhotoReference:A89E1398D0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
5   1947    http://test.nl/doc/PhotoReference:AD7A738ED0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
6   1948    http://test.nl/doc/PhotoReference:A8BA1246D0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
7   1949    http://test.nl/doc/PhotoReference:A8CC0FA0D0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
8   1950    http://test.nl/doc/PhotoReference:A8DF786AD0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
9   1951    http://test.nl/doc/PhotoReference:A8E5A7DAD0B4102DBCF8003048976D84
```